# 'MIX_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, elixir, elixir-mix

```
MIX_ENV=test mix compile
```

...is not working on Windows `cmd`. It shows:

> `'MIX_ENV'` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't use Windows but I think this should work: `set "MIX_ENV=test" && mix compile`.

Answer (score 3):

Like @Dogbert said, in Windows you have to use the `set` command:

```
set MIX_ENV=test && mix compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using other terminals in Windows.

Using commands like `MIX_ENV=dev iex -S mix phx.server` within Git Bash works fine on Windows machines.